# In DDD, can a class that holds a list be a value type?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I have refactored one of my classes and defined a new class called SiteLicenseManager which adds and removes licenses to machines that make up my install site.

The SiteLicenseManager contains a list of LicenseType objects. The contents of each of these objects gets changed depending on if we are adding or removing licenses.

Now, is SiteLicenseManager a value type?

Although SiteLicenseManager does not change (immutable) the contents of the list objects do change (I have them as value objects). However I noticed that I do add LicenseType objects to the list so SiteLicenseManager is in fact mutable.

Also there can only be one SiteLicenseManager instance in my domain.

JD

Comment: Adding and removing objects to/from the list is not DDD. Are there any functional requirements about these objects ? For me it seems to simple to bother with DDD.

Comment: From your description, it sounds to me like your SiteLicenseManager may be a SiteLicense Repository.

Answer (score 1):

You should decide whether your class is value object or entity by its meaning.  If you cannot distinguish between the same license types installed on different sites, it sounds like your license type collection is indeed value object.

SiteLicenseManager is not a good name for a value object.  This name suggests that this objects acts on other objects. I would call it LicenseCollection or something like this.

However, it is absolutely fine to have value objects holding immutable lists inside (License types in your case).  BUT, you should have these lists immutable.

Instead, your value object class should have operations that add/remove licenses by returning new instance of this class.

Something like:

```
class LicenseCollection {
  private readonly ReadOnlyCollection<LicenseType> types;

  LicenseCollection AddLicense(LicenseType type) {
    return new LicenseCollection(/* add new license type to your list */);
  }

  /* constructors etc */
}
```

Whenever you need to change your value object you update it by creating new updated instance. This is similar to what you described, with the only difference that instead of changing lists you create updated copies.